# summary of data in data frame [r]

Tags: r

```
id = c(1,2,3,4)
desc = c("A", "B", "B", "A")
df = data.frame(id, desc)

> df

id      descr
1       A
2       B
3       B
4       A
```

How can I reshape the df to look like:

```
A   B   
1   2   
4   3
```

I've tried dcast, table, etc.

both are character variable. I basically want to go from long to wide but idk what syntax to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `unstack` (assuming that there are equal number of elements in 'id' for 'desc')

```
unstack(df, id~desc)
#  A B
#1 1 2
#2 4 3
```